# What Conformal Field theories are currently known to exist?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, renormalization, conformal-field-theory, big-list

[Conformal field theories](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conformal_field_theory) (CFTs) pop up all over physics, especially in condensed matter and string theory. Their existence puts strong constraints on what quantum field theories can exist, since every quantum field theory must flow to a CFT in the long-wavelength limit (the IR). Classifying all CFTs seems at least as important as classifying all finite simple groups or Lie algebras in mathematics, and indeed there's a lot of effort put into doing this, like the conformal bootstrap.

So given their importance, it would be very interesting to see a list of non-trivial CFTs/classes of CFTs that are known to exist, or are at least strongly suspected to exist based on non-rigorous arguments.

Answer (score 1):

A CFT is a much richer object than a Lie algebra: to a finite-dimensional Lie algebra you can associate an affine Lie algebra, and then build (infinitely) many 2d CFTs based on that affine Lie algebra, and you would just get a tiny subset of 2d CFTs.

Classifying CFTs is therefore hopeless unless you add some restrictions, for example: 2d CFTs with finitely many primary fields. (These are called minimal models.)

Some known CFTs are listed in the relevant Wikipedia articles: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conformal_field_theory and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two-dimensional_conformal_field_theory . The lists cover a small but not negligible fraction of known CFTs. If notable CFTs are absent, someone should add them!

Comment: I was afraid of this, but without knowing much about them, I didn't know what kinds of restrictions you would have to add to get a reasonably-sized list of important CFTs. I know 2D and D>2 are quite different cases, but within these, how could one modify the question to filter for 'CFTs of greatest interest' to modern physics? From what I know about the conformal bootstrap, the space of CFTs that can exist is highly constrained, and people put a lot of effort into only a handful of CFTs.

Comment: It depends which physics you are after. For some applications the CFT has to be unitary, but for statistical physics there is no such restriction. Moreover, for the CFT to be useful, it has to be tractable to some extent. Typically this requires assumptions that the spectrum be sparse enough, for example assuming a lower bound on the gap between the conformal dimensions of the first two primary states. In fact, the space of CFTs becomes highly constrained only if you make highly constraining assumptions.